# Configuring vim for switching between tabs

Tags: vim, configuration

I checked the mapping for `<F8>` and `<F9>` key and nothing is mapped to these two keys.

```
:verbose map <F8>
No mapping found

:verbose map <F9>
No mapping found
```

I'd like to set `<F8>` key to previous tag which is `gT` right now
and `<F9>` key to next tab which is `gt`.

How do I do this?

I read stuff online but none of the hacks worked for me.

Comment: Tab or tags? You seem to be talking about tabs.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake! I was talking about tabs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the following to your vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F8> gT
nnoremap <F9> gt
```

After adding to your vimrc you will need to either restart vim or source your vimrc file again.